# To find $\sum C(n,k)/(k+1) $ for $0 \leq k \leq n$ and k even

Tags: combinatorics

I am stuck on this question for some time now. Let n $\in N$ be fixed.For $0 \leq k \leq n$ and k even, evaluate $\sum C(n,k)/(k+1) $. I know $\sum C(n,k)$ will be $2^{n-1}$ but I am lost while dealing with that additional denominator term. I think I am missing some silly step but can't figure out. Any hint.Thanks.

Comment: Hint: $\frac 1 {k+1}=\int_0^1 x^kdx$. Then swap integral and sum. Finally use the binomial formula.

Comment: And to deal with even $k$, write the sum for all $k$, with $(--1)^k$ as a factor of the general term. Then apply what I said in the previous comment.

Comment: sorry but what is $(−−1)^k$ ?

Comment: See response by Brian below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By the binomial theorem,
$$(1+x)^n = \sum_{k=0}^n C(n,k) x^k \\ (1-x)^n = \sum_{k=0}^n(-1)^kC(n,k) x^k$$
so by adding these, we have
$$(1+x)^n + (1-x)^n = \sum_{k=0}^n\left(1 + (-1)^k\right)C(n,k)x^k = 2\cdot\sum_{\substack{k=0 \\ k\text{ even}}}^n C(n,k)x^k$$
or solving for the sum...
$$\sum_{\substack{k=0 \\ k\text{ even}}}^n C(n,k)x^k = \frac{1}{2}\left((1+x)^n + (1-x)^n\right)$$

Now apply $\int_0^1$ to both sides.